# Python: how to read starting from a specific word in txt file to end of the file

Tags: python

I wanted to read the txt file from a specific word to end of file.

example:

if these are in the .txt file

part A:
contents of part A
part B
contents of part B
part C
contents of part C

in here i wanted to extract or read only from part c or starting from part c

i know to extract from the middle which is

```
with open(file1) as file:
    text = file.read().lower().split("part b")[1].split("part c")[0].strip()
```

but couldnt get for EOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Just split it at part c and take the second item onward from the resulting list.

```
with open(file1) as file:
    text = " ".join(file.read().lower().split("part c")[1:]).strip()
```

I think something like this would work, but it's just pseudocode that I haven't tested FYI

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @Appries I updated it with a possible solution to that. You just join the list into a single string! You may want to exchange " " with "part c" though. It would likely remove that otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple:

```
with open(file1) as file:
    text = file.read().lower().split("part c")[1]
```

Comment: Nope: that gives this error: Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range

Comment: Are you making sure that P and C in `'Part C'` is uppercase? I believe @lunesco made a simple typo there

Comment: I'm converting all to lower case